# The destination directory (/etc) is not writable by the current user on ansible

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, ansible

I am using `Ansible-2.0` on linux machine and I wish to do change DNS on remote machine using ansible as below:

```
---
# tasks file for test
- name: Change dns
   become: yes
   become_user: admin
   replace:
     dest: /etc/resolv.conf
     regexp: '192.168.1.24'
     replace: '8.8.8.8'
```

Output:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i "mn," test.yml 
TASK [test : Change dns]     *******************************************************
fatal: [mn]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "The destination directory (/etc) is not writable by the current user."}

PLAY RECAP     *********************************************************************
mn                         : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

On remote machine, admin is as sudo user and here I don't want to change `sudo` setting on remote machine, Is there any method to pass password using task(script), not using command line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should configure `admin` as a `remote_user`, not `become_user`. The `become_user` option sets to which user you would `su` to execute certain task. In other words, your playbook should look like:

```
---
- hosts: somehosts
  remote_user: admin
  roles:
    ....

#tasks file
---
# tasks file for test
- name: Change dns
  become: yes
   replace:
     dest: /etc/resolv.conf
     regexp: '192.168.1.24'
     replace: '8.8.8.8'
```

That way the admin user will be used to establish your ssh session, but for the `Change dns` task will be used `sudo`.

Also, if `admin` requires password for sudo, you will have to run your playbook like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i mn test.yml -K
```

The `-K` switch will prompt you for the sudo password for `admin`.

Comment: I've remove the `become_user` and added `remote_user` but getting this error `fatal: [mn]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "", "module_stdout": "sudo: a password is required\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}`

Comment: I've edited my answer, please try again.

Comment: using `-b`, not asking remote user password and getting same error, Can we pass the plain password on script

Comment: No, we should not pass the plain password on script, it is an awful practice and it should not be done. How do you connect to the remote machine - is it with a password, or with ssh key?

Comment: accessing remote machine using ssh-key

Comment: try again with the latest change to my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you have sudo access to change destination dir, you can use below var

ansible_user: username

ansible_ssh_pass: password

become: yes

become_method: sudo

ansible_become_password: sudo password